# Kentico 13: User contributions outside of the admin

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-api

I haven't worked with the user contribution webpart from v12 and older, but is it possible to do something similar in v13?

Essentially I'm looking for users to create content outside of the admin site. There's a requirement that logged in users should have their own 'content dashboard' where they can create or edit just their pages. Effectively a cms for their cms. Just looking to see if anyone has run across this before, and if the solution is even possible without the need to build a separate, mini-Kentico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible, we have done it. In v13 however, there is no user contributions webpart (as all portal engine web parts were removed). You need to roll your own code on your live site (the MVC project). From there you can access all the Kentico APIs (as long as you have the nuget packages installed) to insert a node into the tree on behalf of a user. It's just a custom solution.